# "Target machine actively refused" POST request to tensorflow-serving Docker container

Tags: docker, post, network-programming, virtual-machine, tensorflow-serving

EDIT: I needed to portforward the DOCKER virtual machine's port that was paired to the container to my local machines same port.

I am trying to get a response from a tensorflow-serving of a model locally hosted on a docker toolbox container using REST API and am receiving an error for any attempts to connect to it from my host machine. I have exhausted anything I can think of trying or searching for to fix my issue.

I have tried to connect with both localhost:8501 and the IP of docker in 192.168.99.101:8501 nor the IP of the container of 117.17.0.2:8501 with no success.

Here is an imgur album of more details pertaining to my issue for more context, including the docker machine details, the container details, the POST & GET requests I attempted, the VirtualBox stats & the log of the container: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdeBK.jpg

I have also tried disabling my firewall during all of these attempts.

I can ping 192.168.99.101 successfully but not  192.168.99.101:2376 nor 192.168.99.101:8501.

When I enter the Docker container and run the tensorflow_model_server command I get another error which is at the start of the imgur gallery.

My host operating system is Windows 10 home.

I am really not sure if the issue is a networking one where the virtual box  should not be refusing a connection or if it's potentially an issue with the tensorflow-serving side of things.

Thanks for any help in advance!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 196, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002902F3DECC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8501): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002902F3DECC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Charles/PycharmProjects/spamreader/test4.py", line 3, in <module>
    out = requests.get("http://localhost:8501")
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Charles\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 513, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8501): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002902F3DECC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
```

errors message in docker:

```
>   --model_name=prod_mod --model_base_path=/models/prod_mod
2019-01-22 05:21:16.214490: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:82] Building single TensorFlow model file config:  model_name: prod_mod model_base_path: /models/prod_mod
2019-01-22 05:21:16.215026: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:461] Adding/updating models.
2019-01-22 05:21:16.215231: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:558]  (Re-)adding model: prod_mod
2019-01-22 05:21:16.334858: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:739] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: prod_mod version: 1}
2019-01-22 05:21:16.335783: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: prod_mod version: 1}
2019-01-22 05:21:16.336508: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: prod_mod version: 1}
2019-01-22 05:21:16.337655: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/bundle_shim.cc:363] Attempting to load native SavedModelBundle in bundle-shim from: /models/prod_mod/1
2019-01-22 05:21:16.338101: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: /models/prod_mod/1
2019-01-22 05:21:16.355285: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2019-01-22 05:21:16.367139: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2019-01-22 05:21:16.405369: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:162] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2019-01-22 05:21:16.550336: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:138] Running MainOp with key saved_model_main_op on SavedModel bundle.
2019-01-22 05:21:16.571837: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:259] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success. Took 233732 microseconds.
2019-01-22 05:21:16.572396: I tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/saved_model_warmup.cc:83] No warmup data file found at /models/prod_mod/1/assets.extra/tf_serving_warmup_requests
2019-01-22 05:21:16.578072: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:86] Successfully loaded servable version {name: prod_mod version: 1}
2019-01-22 05:21:16.579211: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:286] Running gRPC ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:8500 ...
[warn] getaddrinfo: address family for nodename not supported
[evhttp_server.cc : 222] RAW: Couldn't bind to port 8501
Aborted (core dumped)
root@dce94d95c992:/#
```

Comment: Did the portforward work (mentioned in the EDIT)?
Looking at the container logs posted imgur (output of docker container logs) I do not see any error (except for the benign [warn] getaddrinfo message). if this is still an issue, can you please post the complete container startup command line (docker run) and get request (curl command), with the error message?

Answer (score -1):

This mostly happens because the server you are trying to connect to is not running. I got the exact same error while i was trying to make a flask app using mongo. I got it twice as my mongo server was not running and i was trying to connect to it and the next time when i was trying to connect to another server which was not running. So please check your server.

This can also happen if the host or port are wrong.

If you find a different solution please tell.